# In the zabbix project, how to export historical data about CPU and memory in the past four hours from mariaDB?

Tags: zabbix

I can capture the real-time records of CPU and memory in the web interface of zabbix. The history table in the mariaDB database has data. How should I export the historical data of the past four hours?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct4vN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Historical data is a history-related table that exists, and to get historical data from the CPU or memory, you need to get its itemid first.Find out the host's host from the host table, check its monitoring items according to the hostid, find out the data object you want to get, and query from the history table.

```
select itemid,from_unixtime(clock) as time,value from history where itemid=29096 and clock >= unix_timestamp('2021/05/21 00:00:00') and clock <= unix_timestamp('2021/05/21 17:31:00');
```